# OpenCV for Android: Convert Camera preview from YUV to RGB with Imgproc.cvtColor

Tags: android, opencv, converters, rgb, yuv

I get a runtime error if I try to convert camera preview YUV byte array
to a RGB(A) byte array with Imgproc.cvtColor( mYUV_Mat, mRgba_Mat, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV420sp2RGBA, 4 )
in onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera):

Preview.java:

```
     mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
          public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
          {
            // Pass YUV data to draw-on-top companion
            System.arraycopy(data, 0, mDrawOnTop.mYUVData, 0, data.length);
            mDrawOnTop.invalidate();
          }
       });
```

DrawOnTop.java:

```
public class DrawOnTop extends View {
Bitmap mBitmap;
Mat mYUV_Mat;
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (mBitmap != null)
    {

        canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
        canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();
        int newImageWidth = 640;
        int newImageHeight = 480;
        marginWidth = (canvasWidth - newImageWidth)/2;

        if( mYUV_Mat != null ) mYUV_Mat.release();

        //mYUV_Mat = new Mat( newImageWidth, newImageHeight, CvType.CV_8UC1 );
        mYUV_Mat = new Mat( newImageWidth, newImageHeight, CvType.CV_8UC4 );
        mYUV_Mat.put( 0, 0, mYUVData );

        //Mat mRgba_Mat = new Mat();
        Mat mRgba_Mat = new Mat(newImageWidth,newImageHeight,CvType.CV_8UC4);

        //Mat mRgba_Mat = mYUV_Mat;

        //Imgproc.cvtColor( mYUV_Mat, mRgba_Mat, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21, 4 );
        //Imgproc.cvtColor( mYUV_Mat, mRgba_Mat, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV420sp2RGB, 4 );
        Imgproc.cvtColor( mYUV_Mat, mRgba_Mat, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV420sp2RGBA, 4 );


        // Draw Bitmap New:
        Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( newImageWidth, newImageHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 );
        Utils.matToBitmap( mRgba_Mat, mBitmap );
        mRgba_Mat.release();
}
}
```

The conversion mYUV_Mat.put( 0, 0, mYUVData ) runs correctly.
But the attempts to convert mYUV_Mat to mRgb_Mat using Imgproc.cvtColor
lead all to runtime errors ("Source not found." with Eclipse).

What is the correct Imgproc.cvtColor command for my goal?

(I don't want to use a Java YUV2RGB(A) decode method because it's to slow
for image processing. I want to use the OpenCV Imgproc.cvtColor method
because I can do native calls)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe the `Imgproc` library isn't properly included in your project, but other OpenCV libraries are?  The line that crashes is the first line where you use a method from `Imgproc`, which would explain why earlier parts of the code run correctly.

Your code looks fine, except you can use the no-argument constructor for `mRgba_Mat` (since most OpenCV4Android functions, including `cvtColor`, can infer the required size of the destination matrix), and you're allocating a lot of wasted space for `mYUV_Mat`.  You don't need a full 4 channels if you just allocate YUV matrices 50% more space than their RGB counterparts:

```
mYUV_Mat = new Mat( newImageHeight + newImageHeight / 2, newImageWidth, CvType.CV_8UC1 );
```

Comment: Is not the first argument of Mat constructor a height and the second width? IMO first argument is rows which is in fact height of an image instead of width :P

Comment: Yes, you're right, the arguments should be reversed.  I was adapting the code from the question, which is also incorrectly-ordered.

Comment: Thanks! But I thought that it should be `Mat(height + height / 2, width, CvType.CV_8UC1 )` (_Height_ is first parameter).

Comment: @AlexCohn Yes, it was discussed earlier in the comments but I didn't make the change at the time.  It's fixed now.

Comment: @1'' still the produced mat - mRgba_Mat  does not give the whole three channels , only one channel is active (giving values from 0-255) and other two are 0 why?