# How to use OpenCV methods in Android Camera Preview

Tags: java, android, opencv, camera, android-camera

I want to do some image processing by using Imgproc functions of OpenCV from an image captured by a camera preview.

The problem is that I already use a Camera.PreviewCallback to get images from the Android camera preview. But I saw that in OpenCV we need to use a different preview called CvCameraViewListener2.

So do I have to redo all my stuff from my custom preview to the OpenCV one ? Could I just use OpenCV functions without CvCameraViewListener2 ? Or do CvCameraViewListener2 and Camera.PreviewCallback work the same and It's simple to switch from one to another ?

What I already use :

```
public class MyClass implements Camera.PreviewCallback
```

In OpenCV :

```
public class MyClass implements CvCameraViewListener2 {
```

Comment: `SurfaceHolder.Callback` implements the 3 methods that follow the lifecycle of its SurfaceView, it is not used to capture preview frames. `CvCameraViewListener2` is to certain extent similar to `Camera.PreviewCallback` interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research, thanks to this post : [Unable to use both cameras of Evo 4G using OpenCV4Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959552/unable-to-use-both-cameras-of-evo-4g-using-opencv4android/) I can say that the answer is yes. We can use OpenCV methods without having to use CvCameraViewListener2.

I just initialized the OpenCV lib where I want to use my image processing (explained here step 10 : http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html). Then I can use OpenCV methods.

And I can get the matrix to use with OpenCV for example with:

```
img = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
```

Comment: Note that your `img` is grayscale only. On the other hand, CvCameraViewListener2 lets you receive RGBA. If you need color, look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16704897/192373

Comment: Oh ok this can be useful, in my case I only needed grayscale though but good to know.